# How to use jhipster and react-jhipster-mui generator

Tags: reactjs, jhipster

I would like to use use mui react library with jhipster. There seemed to be module  [react-jhipster-mui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jhipster-mui) which should enable it, but I am not sure how to force jhipster to use it.

I have found simmilar blueprint module which is used by jhipster using --blueprint parameter, see bellow

```
jhipster --blueprint primereact-blueprint
```

unfortunately it doesnt work with latest version of jhipster.
Anyway execution of the module as blueprint doesn't work

```
jhipster --blueprint react-jhipster-mui
```

it ends with:

> The generator-jhipster-react-jhipster-mui blueprint provided is not
> installed. Please install it using command npm i -g
> generator-jhipster-react-jhipster-mui*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-jhipster-mui is not a blueprint, it's a replacement for react-jhipster library.

So you must edit the `package.json` file of your project, replace "react-jhipster" by "react-jhipster-mui" with correct version "1.1.0" and then run `npm install`.

However, it's very likely that it won't work as "react-jhipster-mui" has not been updated for last 6 months since it was forked from "react-jhipster".

If it does not work, you could try to contact its author to see if he/she is interested in updating it or you could make it work by yourself.

Comment: thanks for response. As expected, it doesn't work even i fix the imports in react application.

Comment: Yeah there have been 20 commits on react-jhipster since the fork